# Is Ann Patchett married to her dog?

Tags: commas, conjunctions

In a short review on the occasion of the release of her new book in paperback, *This Is The Story of a Happy Marriage*, by Ann Patchett, the New York Times reviewer wrote:

> These sparkling personal essays, by the author of *Bel Canto* and *State of Wonder,* cover the quotidian and the profound: from Patchett’s passion for opera and **her stabilizing second marriage to her beloved dog**, and her resolve to open an independent bookstore in Nashville.*

Patchett was obliged to answer in a letter to the editor:

> ...When highlighting a few of the essays in the collection, the review mentions topics ranging from “her stabilizing second marriage to her beloved dog” without benefit of comma, thus giving the impression that Sparky and I are hitched. While my love for my dog is deep, he married a dog named Maggie at Parnassus Books last summer...

Style guides vary in opinion on the use of commas. Clearly they are meant to be used to avoid situations exactly like this one.

Many people are using the comma less often. If the *New York Times* *book reviewer* makes mistakes such as this one, what hope is there for the rest of us?

Shouldn't commas simply be used before all *ifs, ands and buts?*

(Also, does the punctuation in any way identify if marrying her dog is of a quotidian nature, or of a profound nature?)

*since corrected

Comment: This is clearly off-topic, and you know it. This should be closed as Primarily Opinion Based.

Comment: Shameless, shameless. But I can't help myself, I have to upvote!

Comment: Wait...so did she marry her dog or not?

Comment: @Robusto - shameless hat-ho-ho-hoing. ')

Comment: Are you posting off-topic questions just to test the system? Or to bolster it ('This should be closed as Primarily Opinion Based')?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - hats!

Comment: Aaagh. I'd go away for a couple of weeks if I hadn't been roped in to play Father Christmas at a Church social. 'And have you used commas sensibly this year, little boy?'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - lol! Give 'em a lump of coal if they don't use the oxford comma!

Comment: Oxford comma? Lists are, of course, banned. They have what they're given. Getting back to linguistics, the correct use of coalons is, of course, a burning issue.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've been Father Christmas twice at a local day nursery. It is ok if you get the 4-year-olds, they love it. But many of the 2 and 3-yr-olds are utterly terrified of you. Anyone hearing the screams would think you were murdering them!

Comment: I'll use the phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the comma shouldn’t be used before every *if*, *and* or *but*. This mistake is easy to understand.

One should not commit an entire people to using superfluous commas, if only for the reason that it continues to provide us with hilarious examples such as this one.